# Switching video on F9 key press

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video, android-videoview

I am trying to switch a unity video on F9 key press in 2D to 3D.
What I am thinking is to play 2d and 3d video parallel and when the F9 key is trigger then switch the video into 3d mode, but I'm not able to do so.
Correct me if it's misleading.

Answer (score 0):

So playing 2 videos at the same time is typically bad for performance, but you can have any key toggle them easily. This code snippet is based on a quick & simple setup; one video per gameobject, objects all stored as prefabs underneath the object with this code snippet:

```
GameObject flatVideo;
GameObject threeDVideo;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F9)){
       flatVideo.SetActive(!flatVideo.activeInHierarchy);
       threeDVideo.SetActive(!threeDVideo.activeInHierarchy);
    }
}
```

If I were you, I would instead look at just changing the VideoPlayer component & VideoClip that a VideoPlayer component is using. You can even skip to certain frames in a video to keep the video playback at the same position even when switching videos.
Check out Unity's documentation on their VideoPlayer component [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-VideoPlayer.html), [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html), and a [tutorial here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/videoplayer-component).

Depending on your target platform, 2 videos playing simultaneously will have a big impact on performance. Buffering between videos might temporarily stop what the user is doing/seeing/experiencing, but will be better for the overall app experience & device hardware & performance.